# Whitespaces in String escaped even with <h:outputText escape="false"

Tags: jsf

In the database and when i make java output the text in the `getText()` method, the text is with normal whitespaces but when the .xhtml is doing the output all whitespaces are transformed to `&nbsp;` i tried it without `h:outputText` and with `escape` `false/true`.

`<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{itemHome.description.text}" />`

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF/Facelets does not do that, but some browsers/plugins (Firebug "Inspect Element" for example will do, but not Firefox *View Source*!) will show that when those spaces are *actually* non-breaking spaces ([U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)) instead of normal spaces ([U+0020](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm)). The problem needs to be fixed on the DB side (or on the input validation/conversion side whenever it concerns user-controlled input).